# trac and subversion - adding comments to a ticket with subversion

Tags: svn, trac

Could anyone please help me with Apache Subversion and Trac?

When I commit a change and say "message closes #123" then my message is displayed inside the actual ticket and shows that it has been fixed.

What I also want to happen is if I want to commit some changes to a file but the problem hasn't been fixed yet then I want my message to be added inside the actual ticket.

Ticket comments: comment:1:ticket:2 ----- Not working!

When I check my timeline then I can see my REV and the above is a link to the ticket but I don't see my message inside the ticket as a comment.

How do I enable this or make it work with an example please?

Comment: How do you integrate Trac with SVN now? What client do you use?

Comment: This may help BTW: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously you've already configured TicketCommitUpdater correctly. What you need, is just the magic word. Here is one:

```
refs
```

Example:

```
This is a changeset message, refs #123.
```

Will create a new comment right below the last one. No need to try to refer to the comment. This can't be done. But the backlink to the changeset, that will be added as prefix to the message should be sufficient anyway.

You didn't ask (yet), but certainly you can mix both:

```
This is another changeset, refs #42, #69 and #121, closes #124.
```

There is even more, just see the [reference documentation on that Trac component](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommitTicketUpdater#Usage).

Comment: You are too awesome dude! Thanks alot. This "refs" isnt documented very well. i had been looking forever! You just made my life a bit easier.

Comment: Great, you're welcome. That's how it is with experts sharing knowledge here. I do appreciate it too for my own challenges.